# Function overloading for "integral" types

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, overloading

Suppose there are types of "temperature"(T) and "distance"(D). Both, indeed, could be declared as usual typedefs:

```
typedef int T; // might be C++11 'using' 
typedef int D;
```

But if I want an overloaded functions:

```
void f(T) {}  
void f(D) {}
```

it will not work, because both types are identical.

**Which most modern C++-way to realize such an overload?**

It is clear that for those types must be distinguishable for compiler.

Comment: `typedef`s (and `using`s in C++11) create aliases. You'll need to make them actual classes to overload on them.

Comment: We've been using `struct{int x;}` to do this since when Bill G was still writing code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) is made *exactly* for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

If you want them to be distinguishable, I'd go for a struct with conversion operator.

```
struct T {
   int value;
   operator int() const {
       return value;
   }
}
```

A simple value class.

If you want something modern, you can add your own used defined literals to directly create instance of T from literals.

```
T operator "" _t(unsigned long long int v){ return {v};}
```

Comment: I think better add `const` to `operator int`.